# Vim indenting file for Treetop (Ruby parser)

Tags: ruby, vim, indentation, treetop

Has anyone seen a vim indent file for [treetop](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/), the Ruby parser/generator? I've found a vim syntax highlighting file, but haven't seen one for indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like it's fairly easy - I just create a file

```
~/.vim/indent/treetop.vim
```

and make its sole contents

```
runtime! indent/ruby.vim
```

and it seems to then support all I need. I think it just wasn't loading Ruby's indentation file!

Comment: Treetop files aren't Ruby though.  They bear a strong resemblance, but that's all.  Are you sure that using Ruby's indent file won't cause any problems?

Comment: it seems to work pretty well so far. parts like do / end seem to be picked up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the one from this guy: http://code.google.com/p/dot-files/source/browse/trunk/.vim/syntax/treetop.vim?spec=svn149&r=149

Works beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

I searched for this a while ago for Vim or Emacs and couldn't find anything so I started writing my
own mode for Emacs. It never got to anything since I pretty much stopped using TT but if my memory
doesn't fail you only have to parse something like:

```
grammar Name
  includes # something like "include Something"

  rule rule_name
    tokens_or_rules {
      inner_method {
      }
    }
    <MyModule>
  end
end
```

Which might not be too hard after reading
[this](http://psy.swan.ac.uk/staff/carter/Unix/vim_indent.htm).

PS: Keep in mind that this grammar is really similar to the one used by RSpec which is natural Ruby so maybe you could get some help by reading that.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if there's a straight ruby implementation, but the  [vim rails plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567) handles indentation quite well.

You could always just edit this so that it supports ruby files that aren't within a rails project. Check it out.